# Find The number of ways?

Tags: permutations

The number of ways in which all the integers from 1 to 36 (both inclusive) 
can be arranged such that no two multiples of 6 are adjacent is expressed as

$$ m! x^n Pr $$
where m, n, r  are distinct  positive integers.

What is the sum m + n + r?

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

*EDIT:* The formula is
$$ m!\times{^nP_r}$$
where $^nP_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r!)}$ is the number of $r$-permutations of $n$ or [sequences without repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics) of length $r$ chosen from an $n$-element set.

Comment: What is $P$? *$ $*

Comment: It stands for permutation.Like n P r. Its x^n P r.

Comment: And what is $x$? "The number of ways in which all the integers from 1 to 36 (both inclusive) can be arranged such that no two multiples of 6 are adjacent" is a constant number. Given such a number, how does one defines $m$, $x$, $n$ and $r$?

Comment: So I think the correct formula is $m!\times{}^nP_r$ (`$m!\times{}^nP_r$`) or $m!\times{}_nP_r$ (`$m!\times{}^nP_r$`) where ${}_nP_r=\frac{n!}{r!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the number of ways, consider that the 30 numbers that are not multiples of 6 can first be arranged and then the remaining 6 can be arranged somewhere in the remaining 31 gaps. So the number is $30!\times ^{31}P_6$. Not sure how x fits into this (tbh looks like a typo).

EDIT: Looks like $x$ here meant multiplication. In that case m = 30, n = 31, r = 6. So m + n + r = 67.

Comment: Wow, you're great at telepathy! It seems that $x$ has been used as a replacement for $\times$ (so that it is not $x$ raised to $n$-th power but rather $P(6, 31)$).

Comment: Thanks Wonder.Wonderful answer.

Comment: Very nice! $nCr={n\choose r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!\,r!}$ ("$n$ choose $r$") and $nPr=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$  ("$n$ permute $r$") are alternate notations for choosing (unordered) and arranging (ordered) $r$ of $n$ objects; apparently some authors also superscript the $n$ as in ${}^nC_r$ and ${}^nP_r$.